Solve for matrix M given C = AM-MB?
Given a matrix $C \in k^{m \times n}$ and invertible matrices $A \in k^{m \times m}, B \in k^{n\times n}$. Can we solve the equation $$C = AM - MB$$ for $M$ in terms of $A, B, C$?
I don't know where to start. I've asked ChatGPT and it says something about vectorization and the Kronecker product, but I don't know anything about either of those.

See - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation

As a practical matter, you can consider your equation as a system of $mn$ linear equations in the $mn$ variables which are the entries of the $m \times n$ matrix $M$, and solve it using your favourite linear algebra software.  If $m$ and $n$ are large, you'll want to take advantage of the fact that the coefficient matrix is sparse.
